# how to solve div preventing anchor from working

Tags: html, css

I am editing a website and one specific anchor link isn't working anymore. It's not my code and I found out it's one div preventing it from working but don't know what exactly is causing it and how to solve..

```css
   .link-1 a {
background: url(/common/image/icon_link_01.gif) 0 50% no-repeat;
padding-left: 16px;
*zoom: 1;
  }

  div.pagetop-block {
    _height: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 27px;
    *zoom: 1;
  }
  
  div.pagetop-block:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  div.pagetop-block p {
    float: right;
    font-size: 83.4%;
    line-height: 1.4;
  }
```

```html
<div class="pagetop-block">
<p class="link-1">
<a href="#pagetop">先頭に戻る</a></p>
</div>
```

Tia!

You can find the full source here:
http://niwashyu.jp/about/outline.html
I only posted the relevant snippet.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you provided does not contain any `<div>` with `id="pagetop"`, so there is very little to talk about ...

Comment: Can you please share the code of other div which are working?

Comment: I just edited the initial post.
There is of course a div with id at the top of the page. 
I also added a link to the webpage with full source available.

Answer (score 0):

Is it mandatory to use P tags?

`<div class = "pagetop-block"> <a href="https://www.google.com/"> back </a> </ div>`

If you modify it as above, the link will work.

Comment: The p will add a picture before the link. 
It is also working when removing the div.

I would like to keep the image in place but have both right, hence the div with float right, I guess..

Answer (score 0):

If it is your menu item then you need to find id name "pagetop", Your menu item may calling id(pagetop)
I have created one demo for you, you can check it out.
[image]
I have added id name pagetop on div of "You are here"

```css
.mb-50{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

div.pagetop-block {
    height: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-top: 27px;
}
    
    
div.pagetop-block:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
    
div.pagetop-block p {
    float: right;
    font-size: 83.4%;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    
    <link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/image/favicon.png" />
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    
    
</head>
<body>
   
    <!-- Queston-1 -->
    <div class="pagetop-block">
        <p class="link-1">
            <a href="#pagetop">先頭に戻る</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mb-50">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
    </div>
    <div class="mb-50">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
    </div>
    <div class="mb-50">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
    </div>
    <div class="mb-50" id="pagetop">
        <h2 style="color: red; margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px;"> You are here </h2>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
    </div>
    <div class="mb-50">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
    </div>
    <div class="mb-50">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos perferendis atque aut, sed ipsa, error accusamus, minus adipisci placeat fugiat quisquam rerum. Voluptatem, animi odit. Necessitatibus veniam excepturi blanditiis at dolorum distinctio consequuntur adipisci sit veritatis hic tempore laboriosam est odit, eius dolorem dicta eum error! Ipsum soluta odit architecto numquam ad, maxime eum perspiciatis consequuntur cupiditate voluptatem deserunt, vero molestiae reiciendis ipsa velit mollitia sequi delectus autem. Dignissimos libero sequi nemo architecto consequatur temporibus veniam labore sint minima mollitia, commodi voluptates corporis aspernatur esse? Esse sunt aspernatur aperiam itaque, nam dicta dolor quae nihil provident saepe quas officiis quis!
    </div>
    
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    
    <script>
        $('.pagetop-block a').click(function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
            }, 2000);
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! On the original page there is of course a div with id="pagetop" :)

Comment: Could you please provide weblink so i can check and let you know more?

Comment: I have added the link in the original question :)